# Give limited user to install driver

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, limited-user-account

I want to give limited users an ability to install all driver type (ex: printer, LAN etc). Is it possible? Any solution will be apreciated.

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: Not only impossible, but would be a Very Bad Thing if it weren't.

Comment: This would be amazingly cool. Just write a driver based on some MSDN sample code and hijack the entire system. Your (advanced, technical, and possibly malicious) users would love you for it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used XP for a long time, but if you know in advance what drivers are required you could pre-install them, or you could put them in the driver store (?) so that Windows automatically finds and uses them when the new hardware is detected?